# I have three fingers. What is this?

Tags: riddle, computer-science

> I have three fingers,
>
> Middle finger has a triangle,
>
> Left finger has a circle and,
>
> Right finger has a square
>
> Put these fingers on your PC

What is this?

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?

Comment: @QuestionAsker Why has this been upvoted? It is pretty much the lowest possible effort that anyone could put into making a riddle.

Comment: @f'' also see the other answer , it made me so shocked , when answer matched the puzzle so well . I don't want upvote for my question , but want see the below answer by Philip Schiff upvoted as much as possible .

Comment: @f'' I think 'simple' looking puzzles are OK as long as they don't have trivial answers. I don't think the answer to this one is obvious. Surely not every question on this website has to be over 10 lines long?

Comment: I was thinking "Generic zero-effort logo" like EA's

Comment: Hey there! Could you please not edit in addendums to titles in brackets? Thank you!

Comment: Helper question: Does the fourth finger have an "X"?

Comment: I thought it was a playstation controller...

Comment: After seeing the answers , I feel world is filled with circle , square and triangle everywhere , Even the badges in Mathematics S.E is circle,square and triangle.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

It's­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

> A USB icon.
> [image]

Comment: I don't think I ever realized how cool that symbol looks

Answer (score 138):

Solution:

> The Azrieli Towers in Tel Aviv

As:

> [image]

Comment: very creative !!

Comment: The amount of different answers on Puzzle Exchange always blows my mind. Great work!

Comment: The ordering of 'fingers' certainly can be safisfied by choosing an appropriate point of view, even though it's not obvious why one of six  directions should be preferred. +1 anyway!

Comment: I printed this picture, but it won't go into my PC :(

Answer (score 28):

You can be :

> Three buttons on a PlayStation game controller
>
>  [image]

Granted most people look at it the other way up :D

Comment: creative !!....

Comment: you missed mini USB icon from RC :)

Comment: This was the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: I guess this answer could be right if you look at the center of the image... ;-)

Comment: However, most people don't put one finger on each button.

Comment: Doesn't meet the *fingers* requirement.

Answer (score 18):

It is probably:

> **The three buttons** on an Android(Lollipop or +) screen.
>  See the encircled buttons :
> [image: ![screenshot with 285x443]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufruZ.jpg)

Note:

> **Assuming** that you have [crossed your fingers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossed_fingers) (index finger and middle finger) to touch your new phone!
> where:  $\vartriangleleft$ is 'Back', $\bigcirc $ is 'Home' and $\square$ is 'Recent'.

Answer (score 8):

Is there a possibility that you are:

> Ninja Turtles
>  [image: Ninja Turtles]

I have three fingers,

> Ninja Turles have 3 fingers in each hand

Middle finger has a triangle,
Left finger has a circle and
Right finger has a square

> A pizza slice is a triangle, and a whole pizza is a circle. There are also popular square shaped pizzas now.
>  Ninja Turtles are glutton when it comes to pizza. I can imagine them stacking 3 pizzas each on one finger.

Comment: nice!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

You could also be

> [image]
>  this design, found on Pinterest.
>
>  Or, more prosaically, you might be
>  [this graphic design studio](http://circletrianglesquare.com/).

Comment: Creative, but doesn't meet the *fingers* requirement.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Card depicting a circle, a triangle and a square]

Just answered, as it has created hype now...

> [Squid Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_Game)

Comment: 'Fingers' though? These are just shapes on their own. (And to anyone tempted to say it: yes, I know there are four and a thumb in a shot... To which I say: '*Three* fingers though?') :)

Comment: Doesn't meet the *fingers* requirement.

Comment: @Tacoタコス, it does: it's probably a video game.