# A riddle I thought of on the bus

Tags: riddle

> As the silhouette of a ball comes forth
>   Sprouts an arrow pointing North
>   To the left contains round borders
>   To the right lies four corners
>   The road is split between these three sections
>   You need me to make connections

What am I?

Comment: I have an answer in mind but it would require switching left and right. Are these definitely the right way round?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling :D Have a new badge by completing a [tour here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This looks like a

> USB symbol: a ball with a North arrow, circle on the left and square four corners on the right.
>
>  [image]
>  <sub>This stands for the Universal Serial Bus so explains the title location.</sub>

Though this answer is the same as, and has similar questions to below, so may be a duplicate.

> [I have three fingers. What is this?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40586)

Comment: +1 Great answer!

Comment: @Tom: I think it could be considered a duplicate just because it shares the same solution with the other question; but this one is a far better riddle (and in my opinion should receive many more upvotes than the other question)

Answer (score 9):

I think the answer might be

> A Playstation controller button pad 
> **Note:** though by the wording of the riddle, this would need to be reflected.

As the silhouette of a ball comes forth

> [image] 
>  The button pad has a circular outline, the silhouette of a ball.

Sprouts an arrow pointing North

> Triangle

To the left contains round borders

> Circle - although this is on the right

To the right lies four corners

> Square - although this is on the left

The road is split between these three sections

> Cross - looks like a road intersection with three different paths

You need me to make connections

> You use the pad to play games and you can connect with people online.

Comment: good one, though I think the right and left is arguable :)

Comment: Actually... why havent i thought of that, good answer. Also, rot13(nyy gur ohggbaf ner vafvqr n pvepyr, naq vs lbh gnxr gur pragre bs guvf pvepyr, guna gur ohggbaf npghnyyl svg cresrpgyl jvgubhg nal punatrf gb gur evqqyr grkg.)

Answer (score 6):

I would say that you are a

> Compass

Because

> The compass is usually round, and circle is silhouette of a ball
>  The arrow of a compass is always pointing north.
>  Borders and corners are markings on the compass - Corners are North, West, South, East. Borders are degree markings on the compass.
>  To navigate using the compass you actually have to use all three in order to determine your position and to find out where are you going

Answer (score 3):

Am I being too literalistic or is this a

> Road Sign for a Roundabout?

As the silhouette of a ball comes forth

> You see the roadsign with the basic round shape of a roundabout

Sprouts an arrow pointing North

> The main road continues straight ahead, or "North" of the roundabout.

To the left contains round borders

> There are no exits to the left.

To the right lies four corners

> There are two minor exits to the right, which are squared "stumps" with two corners each.

The road is split between these three sections

> The road splits into the three exits.

You need me to make connections

> Without the roundabout you can't get off the main road you're on.

I can't find an exact match but:

> Imagine this sign with Orton Centre pointing North and Orton Goldhay, Orton Malborne and the other major exit removed.  Oh and the two "Stump" (minor) exits moved round to the right. 
>  [image]

Comment: You'll need to show me the sign you're talking about because a roundabout sign I looked up is just 3 arrows in a circle which does not meet the criteria of the riddle.

Comment: I can't work out how to hide an image in spoiler tags.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're

> Shadow

Since

> As the **silhouette** of a ball comes forth
>  Sprouts an arrow pointing North
>  To the left contains round borders
>  To the right lies four corners
>  The road is split between these three sections
>  You need me to make connections
>  [image: Example]
>  Shadow is connecting between sections :)